# SignalR external service timed loop - server or client

Tags: signalr, client-side, server-side, long-polling, signalr-hub

I have external services that I want to call every 20-30 seconds and make accessible to the client using `SignalR` but I'm not sure if I should have the client call the server in a JavaScript `setInterval` loop or if I should have the server run its own loop and push the information to the client. I'm looking to do dynamic page updates to show what a user is currently playing on Xbox 360/Xbox One or PlayStation Network.

Currently, I'm calling the server side code from the client in a setInterval loop, but I'm not sure how well this will scale. I had been doing Web API 2 calls through AJAX previously, but that will quickly eat up bandwidth. The external services are not mine so the only way to get simulated real-time results is to send a request to the external services periodically. The only problem I see with doing a server side loop is thread blocking. I don't want to stop the current thread while the loop is running.

Client side code:

```
var profile = $.connection.profileHub;

profile.client.receiveXboxProfile = function (profile) {
    console.log(profile.GamerTag);
};

profile.client.receivePSNProfile = function (profile) {
    console.log(profile.PSNId);
};

$.connection.hub.start()
.done(function () {
    function GetGamerProfiles() {
        profile.server.sendXboxProfile(window.UserName)
        .done(function() {
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log('SignalR ' + error);
        });

        profile.server.sendPSNProfile(window.UserName)
        .done(function () {
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log('SignalR ' + error);
        });
    }

    GetGamerProfiles();

    var id = setInterval(function () {
        GetGamerProfiles();
    }, 20000);


});
```

Server side hub:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task SendXboxProfile(string username)
{
    // Makes call to external service to get Xbox profile
    Clients.Caller.receiveXboxProfile(await xboxapi.GetProfile(username));
}

[Authorize]
public async Task SendPSNProfile(string username)
{
    // Makes call to external service to get PSN profile
    Clients.Caller.receivePSNProfile(await psnapi.GetProfile(username));
}
```

Maybe SignalR isn't the best solution for this problem since I don't control the external services, but I am very intrigued by the concept of SignalR and HTML 5 websockets. In general, is it better to do periodic updates on the client or server with SignalR?

Comment: Is it possible to call the server method only when the user plays another game?

Comment: It would be possible to call the server method when the user plays another game, but I would need to listen for a change and I haven't quite figured that piece out yet.

Comment: In your javascript, you can store the game the user is playing and check it every 30s (more or less depending on what you want). If the game changed => notify the server, otherwise => do not notify the server.

Comment: I ended up going with a System.Timers.Timer loop on the server and triggering an event to send the updated presence information to the client when a user changes games.

Comment: Please would you care to provide an answer to the question in the answers section? I believe this would help people like me to know how exactly you implemented your solution. Thanks